# AS3 - Restart Loop Error

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, restart

I have now figured out that After I restart my game The Enter_frame function is not looping? why is that.

Enter_Frame:

```
public function enter_frame(e:Event)
    {
        trace("rGame = " + rGame);

        _Menu();

        if(mGameStart)
        {
            //Stage & Players

            _PlayerStart();
            _PlayerCon();
            _MoveStage();
        }

        if(rGame)
        {
            _PlayerCon();
            trace("_PlayerCon(): Done");
            _MoveStage();

        }

        if(Game_Over)
        {
            mGameStart = false;
            GameOver();

        }

    }
```

Pipe_Spawn:

```
private function eSpawn()
    {
        for(var i:int = 0; i < ePipeMax; i++)
        {
            var _Pipe:EPipe = new EPipe;

            _Pipe.x = (i * 250) + 640;
            _Pipe.y = Math.random() * 90;

            PipeLayer.addChild(_Pipe);


        }
    }
```

Pipe_Move:

```
public function _MoveStage():void
    {

        //Pipes Move
        for (var i:int; i < vPipeMax; i++)
        {

            var _Pipe = PipeLayer.getChildAt(i);

            if(_Pipe.hitTestPoint(_Player.x, _Player.y, true))
            {
                blink = true;

                Remove(_White);

                Game_Over = true;

            }
            else
            {
                if(_Pipe.x < 241 && _Pipe.x > 234){
                    ScoreReady = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ScoreReady = false;
                    two = true;
                }

                if(ScoreReady && two)
                {
                    Score++;
                    Scores.text = Score.toString();
                    two = false;

                }

                if(_Pipe.x <= -20)
                {
                    _Pipe.x = 640 + 100;
                    _Pipe.y = Math.random()*90;
                }

                _Pipe.x -= xSpeed;
            }
        }
    }
```

Game_Restart:

```
public function restartButton(m:MouseEvent)
    {
        GOSign.y = 1000;
        R_Button.y = 1000;
        Scores.y = 105.65;
        HighScore.x = 500;
        ScoreReady = false;
        two = true;

        HighScore5();

        _Player.x = 240;
        _Player.y = 320;

        //This is where I restart the position of the pipes
        for (var i:int = 0; i < vPipeMax; i++)
        {
            var _Pipe = PipeLayer.getChildAt(i);

            _Pipe.x = (i * 250) + 640;
            _Pipe.y = Math.random() * 90;
        }

        rGame = true;

    }
```

Iv been at this for about two weeks and can not fix it. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Check if you are calling `eSpawn()` twice.

Comment: does "rGame" trace appears? Where do you start enter frame event?

Answer (score 0):

I have found my problem. It was a VERY stupid mistake and I cant believe it took me this long to figure it out. I forgot to reset a variable ~facepalm~. I guess you learn from your mistakes lol